# React JS - How to access props in a child component which is passed from a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react application, I am passing my data from parent to child as props. In my child component, I am able to see the data in props however when I try to access the data, I am getting an error saying "cannot read property of undefined".

I have written my child component like below-

Child Component-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { setData } from '../actions/action'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import {
    Accordion,
    AccordionItem,
    AccordionItemTitle,
    AccordionItemBody,
} from 'react-accessible-accordion';


import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/fancy-example.css';
import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/minimal-example.css';

const ChildAccordion = (props) => {
    console.log(props);

    return (
        <Accordion>
            <AccordionItem>
                <AccordionItemTitle>
                <h3> Details: 
               { props?
                    props.map(d =>{
                        return <span>{d.key}</span>
                    })
                    :
                    ""
               }

                </h3>
                    <div>With a bit of description</div>
                </AccordionItemTitle>
                <AccordionItemBody>
                    <p>Body content</p>
                </AccordionItemBody>
            </AccordionItem>
        </Accordion>
    )
};



export default  ChildAccordion
```

Parent Component-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ChildAccordion from './ChildAccordion'
import { setData } from '../actions/action'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import {
    Accordion,
    AccordionItem,
    AccordionItemTitle,
    AccordionItemBody,
} from 'react-accessible-accordion';


import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/fancy-example.css';
import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/minimal-example.css';


class ParentAccordion extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
      //call to action
      this.props.setData();
  }

  getMappedData = (dataProp) =>{
      if (dataProp) { 
        let Data = this.props.dataProp.map(d =>{
            console.log(d);
        })
      }
  }


    render(){
        const { dataProp } = this.props;
        return (
            // RENDER THE COMPONENT
                <Accordion>
        <AccordionItem>
            <AccordionItemTitle>
                <h3>Policy Owner Details: 
               { dataProp?
                    dataProp.map(d =>{
                        return <span>{d.key1}</span>
                    })
                    :
                    ""
               }

                </h3>
            </AccordionItemTitle>
            <AccordionItemBody>
            <ChildAccordion {...dataProp} />
            </AccordionItemBody>
        </AccordionItem>
    </Accordion>
        );
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        dataProp: state.dataProp
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setData(data) {
    dispatch(setData(data));
  }
})
export default connect (mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps) (ParentAccordion)
```

I am using map function inside as my api response can be array of multiple objects.

Comment: `console.log()` is not reliable. It will show updated values. Try using: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props)))`. I am sure you would see `props` might initially be null or something. Throwing an `if` somewhere in the code would do the thing

Comment: I tried that, get TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined.

Comment: `props.map` - bare in mind props is an object not an array.

Comment: You can't map your props, cause it's object, fix it with prop.yourlist.map

Comment: @jonathangoodman my props has array of object which is my api response.

Comment: @OrkhanJafarov so how else can I iterate as there can be multiple objects.

Comment: Could you show your parent component in the example?

Comment: show what your props contains

Comment: Indeed whats the output from that `console.log`?

Comment: yeap, console.log(props)

Comment: @OrkhanJafarov, my bad, console.log(props) is an object in my child component.

Answer (score 0):

Once you know what the prop that you're passing in is called, you can access it like so from within your child component: `{props.data.map(item => <span>{item.something}</span>}`

```
const Parent = () => {
  return (
     <Child data={[{ id: 1, name: 'Jim' }, { id: 2, name: 'Jane ' }]} />
  );
}

const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.data.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>)}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have updated my component above. I don't think I can use props.data as my props has the entire array of object.

Comment: React will take the props passed into a component in JSX and pass them to that component as an object. Your child component will not receive props as an array.

Comment: Still getting the error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Is the property your mapping over an array?

Comment: My props comes as an object in child component so I think that's the issue. I have also added the check to map only when the data is not undefined but still getting error.You can refer to my code above.

Comment: Your right, props is an object passed to the child component thats a fundamental characteristic of react components. Your array will be a property within that object.

Comment: So right now, the api response has only one object in it so right now when I do console.log(props) , I see the entire object instead of seeing the array as the property of the object.

Comment: @Think-Twice Thanks, I am able to get past that error.Just a small question.If you see my child component is a stateless component so I am adding getMappedData just above my return method which throws error. I am defining my method like- const getMappedData = () =>{}.IS there something wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing dataProp down to ChilAccordian as a prop. So in Child component you should access it using props.dataProp and do map on props.dataProp but not on props directly

ChildAccordian:

```
  <h3> Details: 
           { Array.isArray(props.dataProp) && props.dataProp.length > 0 ?
                props.dataProp.map(d =>{
                    return <span key={d.id}>{d.key}</span>
                })
                :
                ""
           }

            </h3>
```

Also keep in mind that you have to add unique key to parent Jsx element when you generate them in loop like for loop, .map, .forEach, Object.keys, OBject.entries, Object.values etc like I did in the above example. If you don’t get unique id from the data then consider adding index as unique like

```
      <h3> Details: 
           { Array.isArray(props.dataProp) && props.dataProp.length > 0 ?
                props.dataProp.map((d, index) =>{
                    return <span key={"Key-"+index}>{d.key}</span>
                })
                :
                ""
           }

            </h3>
```

Edit: If it is an object then do something like below and regarding using a method to generate jsx elements

```
getMappedData = dataProp =>{
   if(props.dataProp){
            Object.keys(props.dataProp).map(key =>{
               return <span key={"Key-"+key}>{props.dataProp[key]}</span>
            });
   }else{
       return "";
    }
  }

   <h3> Details: 
          {this.getMappedData(props.dataProp)} 
   </h3>
```

Comment: Can I put this map function in a function outside render method and use the key in render method?

Comment: What do you mean by doing .map in a function and use the key in render method? I didn't get your question. Can you please elaborate more

Comment: Can I move the iteration part (map method) in a separate function outside of the render method , for ex- if you see I have used getMappedData for iteration over prop.If yes, then how can I use the key values inside my render method as I am using accordion where I would need the access to key and values inside my render method.

Comment: Also, since prop always comes as an object so I don't think map method will work here.Any suggestion?

Comment: @techiequestie I edited my answer please have a look